# Script does not run correctly. No output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a code that should read a XML file. But it doesn't run and I'm not able to find the problem. I think it has something to do with my laptop.

I've already tried to run it in the normal python3 shell and in there it works perfectly fine.

```
import os 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

tree = ET.parse('people.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

root[0].attrib
```

It should output this : `{'name': 'Samy'}`  and it does in the python3 shell but it doesn't work in the script.

The XML file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<PEOPLE>
        <Person name="Samy">
                <age>99</age>
                <number>0176293747238</number>
        </Person>
        <Person name="Alkoholik">
                <age>20</age>
                <number>0176234923482</number>
        </Person>
</PEOPLE>
```

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't work"? any error, output, anything? how do you run this script?

Comment: Not a single output

Comment: What the command you are using to run it?

Comment: you have to use the print-function:  **print(root[0].attrib)**

Comment: I tried it with the print function but it still gives nothing out

Comment: @KarateKid python3

Comment: please show us your .xml file structure. Try to iterate over the structure with **for i in root.iter():  print(i.tag, i.text)** to see, where your wanted values are stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding the print() function gives you the wanted output.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

XML = 'people.xml'

tree = ET.parse(XML)
root = tree.getroot()

print(root[0].attrib) #{'name': 'Samy'}

for i in root:
    print(i.attrib) #{'name': 'Samy'}
                    #{'name': 'Alkoholik'}
```